# How to make a question mark URL with Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am currently looking to know how to make a question mark *URL* in *Spring Web*. My objective is to use this example *URL* `/person?name=Bob` to get a `List<Person>` named Bob!

> I don't quite get how to do so this don't hesitate to give me more details if possible!

**What I tried:**

```
@GetMapping("/person?name={someName}")
List<Person> getPersonsByName(@RequestParam String name) {

    return personService.getPersonsByName(name);
}
```

**What it does:**

Since I'm doing a wrong mapping, it is not set up.

```
{
    "timestamp": "...",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/person"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestParam` create `?` in URL so you should try this

```
@GetMapping("/person")
    List<Person> getPersonsByName(@RequestParam String name) {
    
        return personService.getPersonsByName(name);
    }
```